# Ruby on Rails 3 - Complex forms with associations between 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, database-connection

I have 3 associated tables:

- **Facts** that have 1 **Restriction** (* - 1)
- And **Restrictions** that have 1 **Feature** (* - 1)

When I create a new fact I need to within the facts new form indicate a value for create a restriction and select one feature. I want to know if the use of complex forms http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1 can be applied to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestions of @MrYoshiji, I was able to solve my problem with this approach:

**#Fact model**

```
 class Fact < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :description, :restriction
 belongs_to :restriction, :dependent => :destroy

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :restriction

 end
```

**#Restriction model**

```
class Restriction < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :threshold, :feature
has_many :facts
belongs_to :feature

accepts_nested_attributes_for :feature  
end
```

**#Controller**

```
def new
    @fact = Fact.new
    @restriction = @fact.build_restriction
    @feature = @restriction.build_feature
    ...

def create
    @fact = Fact.new(fact_params)
    @feature = Feature.find(params[:feature][:id])
    @restriction = Restriction.new(:threshold => params[:fact][:threshold])
    @restriction.feature = @feature
    @restriction.save

    @fact.restriction = @restriction
    @fact.save
    ...
```

**#Facts view**

```
 <%= form_for(@fact) do |f| %>
 ...
     <%= fields_for "fact",@fact.restriction do |restr_form| %>
     ...
         <%= fields_for "fact",@fact.restriction.feature do |feat_form| %>
         ...
```

Any doubt jusk ask.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do as following:

```
# Fact model
accepts_nested_attributes_for :restriction
# Restriction model
accepts_nested_attributes_for :feature

# controller
@fact = Fact.new
@restriction = @fact.restriction.new
@feature = @restriction.feature.new

# view
form_for @fact do |fact_fields|
  # ...
  fields_for @restriction do |restriction_fields|
    # ...
    fields_for @feature do |feature_fields|
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

You should end up with parameters like this:

```
{ 
  'fact' => {
     'some_stuff' => 'some_values',

     'restriction_attributes' => {
       'some_other_stuff' => 'some_other_values',

       'feature_attributes' => {
         'stuff' => 'values'
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.17, I think "accepts_nested_attributes_for" is only available for versions 4. Am i right?

Comment: Nope, Im using it in Rails 3 @user2120716 ;)

Comment: Well, it really worked :D Thanks for the help, i'm gonna put my solution here in order to help someone in the future.